# My Network Printer is printing smiley faces simultaneously!

Tags: 12.04, networking, printing, xerox

I am a junior linux administrator at a university.  We have installed a Xerox Phaser 3250 Network printer yesterday. We have installed it correctly on desktops with ubuntu 12.04.  It works but it prints many extra pages simultaneously with small smiley faces in the corner of the page.

It is a big problem because it does it all the time.

We have more of these printers at other places in our university, also linked up with Ubuntu 12.04 and they all work correctly.

Does anybody know how we can fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is might be in the printers memory i would first try to disconnect it from the wall and network, then hit the power button a few times, give it about five minutes to fully discharge all the power stored within the memory, then plug in the power cable. Hit cancel, reset, then print To see if that clears out the volatile memory further more. To see if it doesn't print the smiley face,if it persists then the problem might be within the non-volatile memory, you might need to use a utility to format that correctly, but its also a possibility that the job is coming in from some ware on the network so then after checking to see if it prints plug in the network cable.

take a look at the support page or maybe a manual about the printer.

http://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-3250/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=macosx